# Get table name for field in database result in Python (PostgreSQL)

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to get table name for field in result set that I got from database (Python, Postgres). There is a function in PHP to get table name for field, I used it and it works so I know it can be done (in PHP). I'm looking for similar function in Python.

[pg_field_table()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-field-table.php) function in PHP gets results and field number and "returns the name of the table that field belongs to". That is exactly what I need, but in Python.

Simple exaple - create tables, insert rows, select data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_a (
    id INT,
    name VARCHAR(10)
);

CREATE TABLE table_b (
    id INT,
    name VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO table_a (id, name) VALUES (1, 'hello');
INSERT INTO table_b (id, name) VALUES (1, 'world');
```

When using `psycopg2` or `sqlalchemy` I got right data and right field names but without information about table name.

```
import psycopg2

query = '''
    SELECT *
    FROM table_a A
    LEFT JOIN table_b B
        ON A.id = B.id
'''

con = psycopg2.connect('dbname=testdb user=postgres password=postgres')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(query)

data = cur.fetchall()
print('fields', [desc[0] for desc in cur.description])
print('data', data)
```

The example above prints field names. The output is:

```
fields ['id', 'name', 'id', 'name']
data [(1, 'hello', 1, 'world')]
```

I know that there is `cursor.description`, but it does not contain table name, just the field name.

What I need - some way to retrieve table names for fields in result set when using raw SQL to query data.

**EDIT 1**: I need to know if "hello" came from "table_a" or "table_b", both fields are named same ("name"). Without information about table name you can't tell in which table the value is.

**EDIT 2**: I know that there are some workarounds like SQL aliases: `SELECT table_a.name AS name1, table_b.name AS name2` but I'm really asking how to retrieve table name from result set.

**EDIT 3**: I'm looking for solution that allows me to write any raw SQL query, sometimes `SELECT *`, sometimes `SELECT A.id, B.id ...` and after executing that query I will get field names and table names for fields in the result set.

Comment: You already knew the table name when you ran the query.

Comment: You can get some info from `explain (verbose) <your query>` at the `Output` node. For your example the output could be `Output: A.id, A.name, B.id, B.name`. Use `format` option to get the info in the desired format: `explain (verbose, format json) ...` for example. But how about more complex queries like `select greatest(A.name, B.name) as name from ...` where the source table can be various for each row?

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to query the [`pg_attribute` catalog](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-attribute.html) for the table qualified column names:

```
query = '''
    select
        string_agg(format(
            '%%1$s.%%2$s as "%%1$s.%%2$s"',
            attrelid::regclass, attname
        ) , ', ')
    from pg_attribute
    where attrelid = any (%s::regclass[]) and attnum > 0 and not attisdropped
'''

cursor.execute(query, ([t for t in ('a','b')],))
select_list = cursor.fetchone()[0]

query = '''
    select {}
    from a left join b on a.id = b.id
'''.format(select_list)

print cursor.mogrify(query)
cursor.execute(query)
print [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]
```

Output:

```
    select a.id as "a.id", a.name as "a.name", b.id as "b.id", b.name as "b.name"
    from a left join b on a.id = b.id

['a.id', 'a.name', 'b.id', 'b.name']
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your solution is built for SELECT *. I'm looking for solution that allows me to run any raw SQL query where I specify what columns I want to retrieve (after SELECT). Then after executing the query I expect to get only selected fields in the result set with field names and table names.

Comment: @dwich `select *` is what your asked for

Comment: You are right, I used SELECT * in the example above. However I'm looking for solution that allows me to use any raw SQL - SELECT * or list fields I want to retrieve (and then find out from which table those field are). I updated the question (EDIT 3).